# Tessellation with glPrimitiveRestartIndex()?

Tags: c, opengl, glsl, shader, opengl-4

I'm trying to draw cube using tessellation and primitive restart index. With using primitive restart index I can reduce index count down to 17, and draw cube with something like this:

```
glEnable(GL_PRIMITIVE_RESTART);
glPrimitiveRestartIndex(0xFFFF);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 17, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, NULL);
```

So, in this case I'm getting strange results, but drawing cube with 36 indices and `GL_TRIANGLES` type works just fine.

How can I use tessellation with `glPrimitiveRestartIndex()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is exactly one primitive type allowed for tessellation: [`GL_PATCHES`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Tessellation#Patches). So you can't tessellate `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`s. You should have gotten a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error when you rendered.

Every `N` vertices will be taken as a single patch to be tessellated, where `N` is defined either by the TCS or by a call to `glPatchParameteri(GL_PATCH_VERTICES, N);`. This is much like `GL_TRIANGLES`: every 3 vertices is a triangle. Each patch is completely separate from every other path. So if `N` is 4, then drawing 8 vertices will generate 2 patches.

This means that there's really no purpose in using [primitive restart](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Primitive_Restart) with tessellation.